# Converting Python dictionary to YAML file with lists as multiline strings

Tags: python, yaml, rasa

I'm trying to convert a Python dictionary of the following form:

```json
{
    "version": "3.1",
    "nlu": [
        {
            "intent": "greet",
            "examples": ["hi", "hello", "howdy"]
        },
        {
            "intent": "goodbye",
            "examples": ["goodbye", "bye", "see you later"]
        }
    ]
 }
```

to a YAML file of the following form (note the pipes preceding the value associated to each `examples` key):

```yaml
version: "3.1"
nlu:
- intent: greet
  examples: |
    - hi
    - hello
    - howdy
- intent: goodbye
  examples: |
    - goodbye
    - bye
    - see you later
```

Except for needing the pipes (because of [Rasa's training data format specs](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/training-data-format/#example)), I'm familiar with how to accomplish this task using `yaml.dump()`.

What's the most straightforward way to obtain the format I'm after?

EDIT: Converting the value of each `examples` key to a string first yields a YAML file which is not at all reader-friendly, especially given that I have many intents comprising many hundreds of total example utterances.

```
version: '3.1'
nlu:
- intent: greet
  examples: "  - hi\n  - hello\n  - howdy\n" 
- intent: goodbye
  examples: "  - goodbye\n  - bye\n  - see you later\n"
```

I understand that this multi-line format is what the pipe symbol accomplishes, but I'd like to convert it to something more palatable.
Is that possible?

Comment: The pipe means that the value to follow is a multi-line string. You should convert the `examples` key first to a yaml formatted string as a value in the json, and then convert the json into a yaml.

Comment: I added some language tags to the code blocks which illustrate that by showing how `examples` in the yaml is all green, denoting that this block is a string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither my `ruamel.yaml` nor PyYAML do give easy access to context when dumping a scalar. Without
such context you can only render strings differently based on their content and you cannot
determine if a list/sequence is the value for a particular key and dump it in a different way then some other value.

As @larsks already indicated you need to transform the Python list values into a string. I suggest however
to do that before dumping with a recursive function so that you do have the necessary context. In
this case it is possible to do that in place, which is usually the more easy option to implement.
If that is unacceptable (i.e. you need to continue the data structure unmodified after dumping), you
can either first make a `copy.deepcopy()` of your data, or modify the `transform_value` to create
that copy and return it (recursively).

`ruamel.yaml` can round-trip your requested output (specifically preserving the literal scalar as is).
If you would inspect the type of the value for the key `examples`. You see that it is not a string,
but a `ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString` instance. That instance behaves like a string
in Python, but dumps as a literal scalar.

```py
import sys, io
import ruamel.yaml

data = {
    "version": "3.1",
    "nlu": [
        {
            "intent": "greet",
            "examples": ["hi", "hello", "howdy"]
        },
        {
            "intent": "goodbye",
            "examples": ["goodbye", "bye", "see you later"]
        }
    ]
 }

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

def literalize_list(v):
    assert isinstance(v, list)
    buf = io.StringIO()
    yaml.dump(v, buf)
    return ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString(buf.getvalue())

def transform_value(d, key, transformation):
    """recursively walk over data structure to find key and apply transformation on the value"""
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k == key:
                d[k] = transformation(v)
            else:
                transform_value(v, key, transformation)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for elem in d:
            transform_value(elem, key, transformation)
    

transform_value(data, 'examples', literalize_list)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
version: '3.1'
nlu:
- intent: greet
  examples: |
    - hi
    - hello
    - howdy
- intent: goodbye
  examples: |
    - goodbye
    - bye
    - see you later
```

The string value `3.1` needs to be quoted, in order not to be loaded as a float. By default this is dumped
as a single quoted scalar (which are easier/quicker to parse in YAML than double quoted scalars).
If you want it dumped with double quotes you can do:

```
data['version'] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString(data['version'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for the `examples` value to be represented in your YAML output as a multiline string using the block quote operator (`|`).

In your Python data, `examples` is a list of strings, not a multiline string:

```
{
    "intent": "greet",
    "examples": ["hi", "hello", "howdy"]
},
```

Of course a Python list will be represented as a YAML list.

If you want it rendered as a block literal value, you need to transform the Python value into a multi-line string (`"examples": "- hi\n- hello\n -howdy"`), and then you need to configure the `yaml` module to output strings using the block quote operator.

Something like this:

```
import yaml

data = {
    "version": "3.1",
    "nlu": [
        {
            "intent": "greet",
            "examples": ["hi", "hello", "howdy"]
        },
        {
            "intent": "goodbye",
            "examples": ["goodbye", "bye", "see you later"]
        }
    ]
 }

def quoted_presenter(dumper, data):
    if '\n' in data:
        return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='|')
    else:
        return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='"')

yaml.add_representer(str, quoted_presenter)


for item in data['nlu']:
    item['examples'] = yaml.safe_dump(item['examples'])

print(yaml.dump(data))
```

This will output:

```yaml
"nlu":
- "examples": |-
    - hi
    - hello
    - howdy
  "intent": "greet"
- "examples": |-
    - goodbye
    - bye
    - see you later
  "intent": "goodbye"
"version": "3.1"
```

Yes, this quotes everything (keys as well as values), but that's about the limits of our granularity using the `yaml` module. Without the custom representer, we would get instead:

```yaml
nlu:
- examples: '- hi

    - hello

    - howdy'
  intent: greet
- examples: '- goodbye

    - bye

    - see you later'
  intent: goodbye
version: '3.1'
```

That's syntactically identical; just with different formatting.

It's possible that [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) provides more control over the output format.

Comment: Your output doesn't load to the same data as the OPs requested output. You should get rid of the dash after the literal scalar indicator (`|`) in your output. This dash is caused by `represent_scalar` not appending a newline to the resulting string, so just add that yourself before returning the result ( `....data, style='|') + '\n'` ). It is less efficient (time & space) to have PyYAML dump to a StringIO buffer and then print that, than to directly stream out  using `yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)`